# Calling a web service from android locally

Tags: android

I've built a web-service which i call from my android application.My problem is that when i want to connnect my mobile with my laptop and call this service locally without using internet.(Provided that my server runs locally) how can i do that?I know that there is a shell property when running the avd but how can achieve this when i run it from a tablet which is in the same lan with my server?Thank you for your time.

Comment: Use your IP address, httppost= new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/my_folder_inside_htdocs/check.php"); 
            //Ip address instead of 10.0.2.2

Comment: ok,i'm sorry if i'm tiring you but let me get this straight.now i use http://something.something.com/something.svc,that is my service's url.How do i add the internal ip?

Comment: You must be running web service on some server (on your computer), right? When you will run the server, it will be hosted locally. So, can you can call your something something dot com by using your local ip address e.g. xxx.1.222.32/something.svc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to call a web service using Internet, you use the external ip and port of the server. But if you want to call your web service locally (without the use of Internet), you need to use the internal ip of your server. You can see your internal ip from Windows command *ipconfig* or linux command *ifconfig*

Comment: ok i get in theory.But what i need to call my web service is the url.You mean that i must add the internal ip in the url?

Comment: Precisely. If you call your ws using, for example this url; `http://YourExternalIP_or_YourDomainName/YourFolder/YourService?parameter=...` it should be converted to `http://YourInternalIP/YourFolder/YourService?parameter=...`

Comment: where do we place webservice folder in local pc

Comment: @Lalit does this matter? After all, your PC should be _hosting_ the web service, and you should be able to test your ws by hitting **http://YourInternalIP/YourFolder/YourService?parameter=...** from your local browser(IE, Firefox, Chrome, etc.) This is just a decision of your directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

How your phone and your laptop connected ? 
To use web service running in your laptop you need to run both in same network, for example your need wifi router which connect your laptop and mobile in network. when you connect your laptop with wifi router using cable or wifi , router will assign one ip to your laptop, you can use that Ip in your mobile application to access web service,

In Short: need network between your phone and laptop

Comment: yeah i know.I said that they are on the same local area network.

Comment: to check accessibility between your laptop and phone, 1. open browser from mobile phone, 2. open link http://<laptop ip>:<port> provide your web server port if you have, if default page of your web server is display then everything works, Another option is you can install RESTClient in Android application, open google Play , search "rest client" install any client and call your web service.